# Permission error when creating package version with Custom Object

Tags: salesforcedx, profile

I am trying to restructure my code for sfdx, but a lot of it is (unsurprisingly) built on custom objects. One of the packages I'm trying to create has a custom object that is a detail in a master-detail relationship with Account.

Every time I try to create a new package version, I get errors about permissions from profiles specific to my Dev Hub org. This confused me because these profiles are not present in my packages yet since I didn't want to deal with the complexity of profiles just yet.

Nevertheless, these profiles are causing errors.

Since I'm creating package versions including components that already exist in my org, these profiles have View All access to my detail record. The error is:

```
[My Profile Name]: Permission Read All Custom_Object__c depends on permission(s): Read All Account
```

(Profile and custom object name changed for the above.)
I get that error for every profile with the Read All permission on my custom object. Those profiles *also have Read All* on the Account object.

I'm a bit baffled and frustrated with sfdx. I was hoping it would make my life easier but instead it's proving impossible to break up my org because SF won't let me deploy components independent of permissions.

Does anyone have any ideas or suggestions?